# How to properly collect the input values inserted by the user using jQuery to send them to the server using ajax post?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a payment page that has a multi-step form. In the "step 1" the user inserts  his information like nama, surname, etc, then billing information.

So, in the "step 1" I have fields like name, surname, etc. I want in each step collect all information with jQuery so that is possible to send an ajax request to the server to validate the information when the "go to step 2" button is clicked.

My doubt is about how to properly store this step1 data inserted by the user to be possible to send it to the server. For example in the step 1 Im getting the values like:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
```

Then how to send the data to the server using an ajax post request?

**step 1 html**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <h6>User Info</h6>
    <form method="post" action="">
         {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control"  value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
        </div>
        <!-- other form fields -->
        <input type="submit" id="goToStep2" href="#step2"
                class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

For the ajax part when "Go to step 2" is clicked I created a route 'storeUserInfo', but do you know how to send the data to the PaymentController?

```
$("a[id='goToStep2']").on('click', function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('products.storeUerInfo',null) }}',
        type: 'POST',
         success:function(result){
         ),
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error.status)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can store that information in a session and use them later on. But I don't see the need to submit the form for every step. Better would be to hide the previous steps and just submit the form as a whole. [This should be a good example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp)

Comment: Thanks. Each step is necessary to send an ajax post request to validate the information in each step.

Comment: If you want to validate the inputs you can just attach it to each time the next button is clicked. But you shouldn't have multiple forms for each step as that is unnecessary. You can, however, attach an ajax request on the onclick function for the next button and validate the inputs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete  solution for form with file element

**HTML**

```
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <h6>User Info</h6>
        <form method="post" action="" id="page-form">
             {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control"  value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
            </div>
            <!-- other form fields -->
            <input type="submit" id="goToStep2" href="#step2"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    'use strict'

    var page_form_id = "page-form";

    $('#a[id='goToStep2']').on('click', function () {
        $('#' + page_form_id + ' .error').html("");
        $('#' + page_form_id + ' .form-group').removeClass("has-error");
        var custom_form = $("#" + page_form_id);
        var custom_params = custom_form.serializeArray();
        var custom_files = $("#file")[0].files;
        var custom_formData = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < custom_files.length; i++) {
            custom_formData.append("file", custom_files[i]);
        }

        $(custom_params).each(function (custom_index, custom_element) {
            custom_formData.append(custom_element.name, custom_element.value);
        });

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: '{{ route('products.storeUerInfo',null) }}',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: custom_formData,

            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.reload();
                }, 3000);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                var errors = data.responseJSON;
                $.each(errors['message'], function (index, value) {
                    $('#' + add_form_id + ' .eMsg_' + index).html(value[0]);
                    $('#' + add_form_id + ' .eMsg_' + index).parent().parent().addClass("has-error");
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use form to send something. Better Use submit form method on JQuery. And give return false on the end of the function.

To check is it working, you can use inspect element on your browser on the console tab. If you see something error status it's maybe your code has something wrong.
In other way you can go to the url manually, without hitting by ajax. So you must make sure it works, before you want to use ajax.

Comment: Like this?  $( "#step1form" ).submit(function( event ) {
                alert("hi");
                event.preventDefault();
                var $form = $( this ),
                    name = $form.find( "input[name='name']" ).val(),
                    url = $form.attr( "action" );

                // Send the data using post
                var posting = $.post( url, { s: name } );

            });

Comment: Like that the validation is not working, I dont know if the information is going to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of gathering all of the data into variables separately, use the form online to submit inside your ajax call. First, call `preventDefault()` on the Event, and then you can use this line in your ajax call:

`data:$('#myForm').serialize(),`

PS, you add the event object as a parameter in your click listener. Then you can call `event.preventDefault();`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("a[id='goToStep2']").on('click', function(){ var name = $('#name').val();
$.ajax({ url: '{{ route('products.storeUserInfo',null) }}/' + category_id, type: 'POST',
    data:{ "name": name},success:function(result){ ), error: function(error) { console.log(error.status) } }); });
```

Comment: Thanks the category_id was a typo I update the question. But Im not understanding how in that example the input values are stored in JS and send to the server.

Comment: In the example you've posted above no data is sent to PHP since there are no variables present in the AJAX post request.